# How do the EFE constrain the initial hypersurface?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor

I read that 4 of the 10 EFE constrain the metric on the initial hypersurface, while the other 6 evolve it over time.  How does that happen exactly?  For example, how much would you need to know in order to figure out the metric of the entire hypersurface?  Like, would it be enough in principle to know the metric and its first derivatives in one 2D plane, and use the 4 hypersurface equations to extrapolate that to the entire 3D space?  Then assign the metric derivatives in the 4th dimension and use the other 6 equations from there?

One confusion I have is that a 3D space has 6 metric/Ricci components, not 4.  Of course, the Ricci tensor kind of mixes up the dimensions, so I get why those 6 components are not *exclusive* to the hypersurface.  But I'm not sure how you would separate out 4 equations that *are* exclusive to the hypersurface.

Or is there a more physical explanation for what the initial constraints amount to, in terms of energy or something?

And does the initial hypersurface always have to be entirely spacelike, or could it be a mixture, or even all timelike/null?

Or if it's too complicated to explain and anyone knows a good online reference that does so, that would be awesome.

Comment: +1, I had this same question for averaging problem in cosmology

Comment: I would recommend reading a review [paper by Bartnik & Isenberg](http://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0405092).